# How control autosizing of object without IB?

Tags: ios, ios5, custom-controls, rotation, autosize

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{

    return YES;

}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

    [self positionViews];  

}


-(void)positionViews {

    UIInterfaceOrientation destOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
    if (destOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        destOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

        [bLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(255, 10, 270, 60)];

    } else { 


        [bLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(377, 10, 270, 60)];

    }   
}
```

`bLabel` is Cutomed Object.

When IPad(device) rotates, `bLable` is rotated. 
But appear time lag.
So rotation motion is not smooth.

What is my code's faults?
How control autosizing of object without IB naturally?

Please tell me your advice. Thanks!!!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The property you are looking for on the view is autoresizingMask.Set this just as you would in IB. Here are the values available:

```
UIViewAutoresizing
Specifies how a view is automatically resized.

enum {
   UIViewAutoresizingNone                 = 0,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin   = 1 << 0,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth        = 1 << 1,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  = 1 << 2,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin    = 1 << 3,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight       = 1 << 4,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin = 1 << 5
};
```

For example, if you want a flexible width and height with fixed margins you would do:

```
[myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleWidth;][1]
```

Comment: I'm up against a brick wall. If possible, please look see my other question. Thanks! link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265861/about-trouble-of-device-rotation-using-mtlabel

Answer (score 2):

You can either :

1. set your UIView's autoresizingMask, if it can be
   automatically resized for you.

   ```
   bLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
   ```
2. If the layout between 2 device orientation is too different, you can also change your views in the UIViewController's method `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` which is called during rotation animation, instead of using `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` which is called AFTER the animation transaction.

Any changes you call on your views' animatable properties *(frame, bounds, center, transform, alpha, backgroundColor, contentStretch)* from `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` will also be animated during the rotation.

Comment: Thank's your reply. Difference of two methods become known because of you. Thank you!!